# removeFromSuperview時にanimateWithDurationのcompletionにEXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift

下記のように階層化されたViewがあるとします。

MainViewController: ViewController
　|- A_UIView: UIView
　|- B_UIView: UIView
　|- C_UIview: UIView
　　　　|- C_a_UIView: UIView
　　　　|- C_b_UIView: UIView

全てのUIViewで、自分の子要素を削除するためにdeinit内に下記の記述をしています。

```
deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    var subviews = self.subviews
    for subview in subviews {
        subview.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

MainViewControllerからC_UIViewを削除する時の記述は下記の通りです。

```
self.C_UIView!.removeFromSuperview()
self.C_UIView = nil
```

すると、階層の深さに関係なくUIViewの中にあるanimateWithDurationについて、completionでEXC_BAD_ACCESSが発生してしまいます。

```
UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(
        0.7,
        animations: {[unowned self]() -> Void in
        self.alpha = 0.0
        return
    },
    completion: {[unowned self](Bool) -> Void in <-この行で！
        self.hidden = false
    }
)
```

completionを削除すると問題なく動き、またどのアニメーションだから特別に発生するということはなく、おそらく参照や多重解放などが原因かとは思うのですが、親がremoveされた時に子供も全てremoveするにはどのような方法がベストなのでしょうか。

Comment: 確認したいのですが、なぜ親がremoveされるときに子をremoveFromSuperviewしたいのですか？

Comment: 画面切り替えの機能で、見ていない間のViewでも色々なアニメーションやNotification、http通信が動いているので、閉じた画面のものはUIViewごと削除しようかと思った次第です。再度開いたときに再作成する流れです。

Comment: その子が親のsubviewsからの参照のみであれば、親が解放されたことで子を参照するものはいなくなるのではありませんか？　親が削除される前に子を明示的に親からremoveする必要はありますか？

Comment: はい、最初はそう思いnilを代入するだけにしていたのですが、そうするとdeinitが呼ばれませんでした。明示的にremoveすることでdeinitが動作し、通知やタイマーを削除することができました。お恥ずかしながら今回が初めてのios開発でメモリ関係など本当に手探りで、nilで不十分なのは私の組み方がまずく強参照が残っている可能性もありますよね。しかし今更見直す時間もなく、removeで解決できるならそれで、と思っていました。

Comment: UIViewには `willMoveToSuperview()` という関数があり、superviewが変更されたときに内容が実行されます。親がremoveされ、子がsuperviewを失った際も呼ばれます。deinitに書いているものを子の `willMoveToSuperview()` 内に移し、親のremoveのみで目的が達成できるか検討してみてはどうでしょうか。結果次第で、この質問の前提が崩れると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。C_UIviewにはdeinit、C_a_UIView（今までエラーでストップしていたUIView）にはwillMoveToSuperview()を記述し、MainViewControllerからC_UIviewをremoveしてみましたが、やはり同じ箇所で止まってしまいました。

Comment: 「止まる」とは、どこで、なにが止まっているのでしょうか。まだfor文を使用しているということですか？　じぶんが提案しているのは、親が解放されるのにわざわざfor文を使って子にremoveFromSuperviewをさせるな、ということです。そのための代替案を提示しています。

Comment: もうひとつ補足すると、ご存知かもしれませんが、deinitはインスタンス解放時に呼ばれますが、インスタンスはどこからも参照されなくなっても即時解放されるわけではありません。本当にdeinitが呼ばれないのか、期待よりも遅延しているだけなのか判断してください。その上で、問題にしているコードがそもそも本当に必要なのか考えてください。

Comment: コメントなので詳細を省き失礼いたしました。止まるとはC_a_UIView内のイベントのcompletionでEXC_BAD_ACCESSが発生することになります。また、もちろんfor文でのremoveは行っておらず、現在は通知を止めるNSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)のみ記述しております。今回希望している動作はマストではありませんし、代替案で対応することはできますが、後学のためにクリアしておきたいという気持ちがあります。

Comment: なるほど。ということは、「親がremoveされた時に子供も全てremoveするにはどのような方法がベストなのでしょうか」という質問は本当の焦点ではないかもしれません。この問題を他人でも再現できる最小のコードを別に用意できますか？　解決が早まるかもしれません。

Comment: 申し訳ありません。。現在のプロジェクトが大規模になってしまっており、再現用のコードが容易に準備できません。参照が残ったまま画面切替のたびにメモリが増えていくのでは怖いなと思い解決を目指しましたが、後学のためとはいえ納期に間に合わなければ本末転倒なので、今回は代替案を考えて対応してみようかと思います。何度もご返信頂きまして誠にありがとうございました。

Comment: そうですか。`UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState()` から始まるコードをどこに書いているのか明確にするだけでも回答者の疑問は晴れると思いますが、必要ないようですね。

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESSについて、どうやらanimateWithDurationを入れ子にすることでselfが原因で発生するようでした。なぜremoveのタイミングで起こるのかまでは分かっていませんが、入れ子をやめることでエラーは出なくなりました。取り急ぎご連絡させていただきます。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

かなり時間が経っていますが、原因が確実になりましたので自己レスいたします。

結果的に原因は[unowned self]でした。

この記述を[weak self]に変更し、selfのものが参照されたときにnilであれば参照しないようにしてやることで、落ちることがなくなりました。

ありがとうございました。

Answer (score -1):

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(
    0.7,
    animations: {[unowned self]() -> Void in
    self.alpha = 0.0
    return
},
completion: {[unowned self](Bool) -> Void in <-この行で！
    self.hidden = false
}
```

これのselfは、UIViewControllerのサブクラスではなくて、UIViewのサブクラスですか？
だったら、スレッドの無駄づかいを避ける意味でも、UIViewのアニメーションは、UIViewControllerのサブクラスに記述したほうがいいと思います。

（以下は、役に立たない情報として、削除しようと思いましたが、まあ、役に立たないという事実もまた、だれかの役に立つかもしれないと思い、残すことにしました。「for - in」構文で、subviewsの全削除はできるらしいです。）

後に、ご質問の内容全体について検証するつもりですが、ぱっと見、これはまずいだろうと思った箇所があったので、そこだけ回答したいと思います。

```
var subviews = parentView.subviews
for subview in subviews {
    subview.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

ループを回しているあいだ、subviewsは、内容が変化し続けます。そういうループは予測のできない不具合が起きる危険があります。
配列の要素を全削除というプログラムは、最後尾の要素から削除していくのが、定番です。

```
// var subviews = parentView.subviews // この行はいらない。というか間違い。
while parentView.subviews.count != 0 {
    parentView.subviews.last?.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございました。同様のことをやっている部分を見直してみます。　また、ソースの中で「parentView」となっている部分は「self」です。記事を編集いたしました。ファンクションの中身を記載したので引数名になっていました。失礼いたしました。

Comment: 先ほどの件は間違っていましたのでコメントを削除しました。挙動は引き続き変わりありませんでした。

Comment: @harawo 上記のwhileを使った処理は終了条件を満たすことがないので無限ループになります。ここで行われているのは「配列の要素を全削除」という処理ではなく、ビューの配列の各要素に`removeFromSuperview()`を呼ぶという処理なので、subviewsの中身は取り出した時点から変化しません。なのでsubviews変数はlet指定も可能です。私はこの処理においてはforループで先頭から処理するのも問題ないと考えます。（もっと良い書き方はありますが）

Comment: あ、無限ループになることはありませんよ。ただlastの返り値はオプショナルなので、?をつけなければいけません。そこは修正しました。

Comment: すみません、実は無限ループになりました。。なので、for文に突っ込む前のsubviewsをreverseで逆にして最後から消すようにしてみましたが、相変わらず同じ箇所でエラーが出てしまいます。

Comment: @Harawo ちゃんと動かして確認していますか？あなたの示したコードでは`subviews`の`count`がゼロになることはないので、whileループの終了条件を満たすことはありません。

Comment: @ kishikawa katsumi あ、なにをおっしゃりたいのか、いま理解しました。修正したのでご確認ください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。「UIViewのアニメーションは、UIViewControllerのサブクラスに」とありますが、C_a_UIViewのようにUIViewControllerから孫にあたるようなUIViewのアニメーションもUIViewControllerで管理してアニメーションの指示をした方が良いのでしょうか？

Comment: @ika 私のいいたいことのポイントは、アニメーション処理は一箇所で行いましょう、という点です。アニメーションは非同期処理です。複数箇所でアニメーションをしたら、アニメーションのタイミングが重なる可能性があります。そして、あるオブジェクト（インスタンス）に、異なるアニメーションから、矛盾する処理が行われる危険が潜むことになります。それを避けましょうというのが、私がいいたいことです。一箇所だけとなると、自然それはControllerの付いたクラスになるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。その点は通知等を使って矛盾のないように作っておりますので大丈夫です。（通知を使うことでメモリを多少使うかも、という懸念はありますが..）